# Magento : How to put already created static block after all product listing and end of the sidebar in magento?

Tags: css, magento, static-block

I have 2 column left sidebar theme in magento. I have 3 static block already created. Now i want to display these blocks after all product listing and before footer. How can i do ?

I already tried out but these blocks are mixed up with new product.

Comment: Please show what you've done so far.  Include xml files and templates you've edited for example and what changes you attempted.  This will help us help you.

Answer (score 0):

how familiar you are creating a extension and ad your custom code?. if I understand correctly you want to display 3 different static blocks before footer but after the product list right? in the main column.

Here is what I doing if I need to add something static only for the product list.

1. You need to create a local.xml file under your package/theme in layout using in your site.

```
<!-- Catalog Category (Anchor) -->
<catalog_category_layered>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="cms/block" name="cms_footer_links" after="category.products">
            <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>static_block_1_identifier</block_id></action>
        </block>
        <!-- Add the same for the rest of the other static blocks 2 and 3 -->
    </reference>
</catalog_category_layered>
```

Add the same code to the N-Anchor Display mode

```
<!-- Catalog Category (Non-Anchor) -->
<catalog_category_default>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="cms/block" name="cms_footer_links" after="category.products">
            <!-- The content of this block is taken from the database by its block_id. You can manage it in admin CMS -> Static Blocks -->
            <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>static_block_1_identifier</block_id></action>
            <!-- Add the same for the rest of the other static blocks 2 and 3 -->
        </block>
    </reference>
</catalog_category_default>
```

I did without testing the code but I think should be work, let me know if you have any problem with the code and we can review.